# Getting a data attribute from a javascript

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to insert a url into the data-url using javascript, and I am getting nowhere since I have no clue what I am supposed to do

Here is my html example

```
<a class="button" data-url="http://www.google.com" href="#"></a>
```

all I have at the moment is within my javascript the following:

```
var link = {
    url: 'http:www.google.com'
  }
```

but now I don't know how to get link to be pushed inside the data-url="".

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getAttribute` just like you would any other attribute:

```
var url = document.querySelector('a.button').getAttribute('data-url');
```

Before going down that route, though, I hope you've carefully considered storing the url in the `href` attribute instead, which will - depending on your use case - probably be preferable in terms of graceful degradation.

Comment: And to set a value you can do: `$0.attributes['data-url'].value = 'https://example.com'`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use dataset like `document.querySelector('a.button').dataset.url`

Comment: +1 As far as accessing the data set goes, I'll favor this over my own reply, but I still think `href` should be used even in a majority of cases where the author assumes it shouldn't.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `attributes` property of element.

```js
var data = $('[class="button"]')[0].attributes[1].value;
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="button" data-url="http://www.google.com" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: I don't feel comfortable with hard-coded `[0]`s and `[1]`s. As long as there are solutions which do not require to do it I'm going to do it the other way

Comment: If you're going to assume jQuery, you might as well go all the way and get `$('.button').data('url');`

Comment: @Sebastian: As for the `[0]`, to be fair, other responses utilizing `querySelector` rather than `querySelectorAll` is still a hard-coded assumption that the first match should be grabbed. As regards the `[1]` on the attribute list, I'm entirely with you, though.

Answer (score -1):

Hi all many thanks to your input, it enlightened me as in how to complete this.

I did the following:

```
    var link = {
      url: 'http://www.google.com'
    };

    var el = document.querySelectorAll('a.button');

  el.forEach(element => {
    element.setAttribute('data-url', link.url);
  });
```